# collapse_key, apns-collapse-id not working on iOS in Push messages via Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I trying to update sended push, using collapse mechanism.
I read many docs and info about it, but failed to achieve significant results.

It is work only for Android. I need in iOS too.

What i send to firebase:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "CE2BSR7TwxPY . . . gbWKvBu3SFWh9dHECOIQT6v"
  ],
  "data": {
    "pushId": null,
    "target": "screen",
    "value": "main",
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "Some title..6",
    "body": "2 push apns-collapse-id. 30 attempt",
    "sound": "default",
    "mutable-content": 1,
    "badge": 0,
    "tag": "test"
  },
  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-collapse-id": "test"
    }
  },
  "collapse_key": "test"
}
```

I send 2 pushes with the same `collapse_key`

And result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwjQU.jpg)

This is iOS 12+. On another iPhones is the same result.

where did i go wrong?
Collapse this even possible on iOS?